# Why VS2013 code coverage is analyzing unit test assemblies? how can i disable it for unittests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

I don't understand that why code coverage is analyzing unit test assemblies, as you can see also in [linked video.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Improving-quality-with-unit-tests-and-fakes#c635254566196785417) 
I think it make sense to check coverage for production code but not for the unit test assemblies.
Please tell us if this is a bug in VS2013 or some other reason.

I found about runsettings but switching from testsettings would  ignore testsettings' deployment (where i can specify test data  files and directories to deploy in addition to the target assemblies).

ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute would be nice for new projects 
but what about projects migrating from VS2010

Answer (score 2):

this MSDN article may help you out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

Especially the include and exclude section of the article.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks MikeScott8, but problem with .runsettings file is deployment how we can tell MSTest to include my test data file e.g. (some xml data), so i can not run unit tests and analyze code coverage, if unit test fails to get test data then unittests failing and can't analyze code coverage.

Comment: Be sure if you attempt to follow the sample and use the attribute excludes that you escape the dots: <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Visual Studio Code Coverage tool analyzes all solution assemblies (.exe/.dll) that are loaded during unit tests.

If you want to exclude the test code from the code coverage results and include only the application code - Add the `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute to your test class.

If you want to include assemblies that are not part of my solution. Obtain the `.pdb` files for these assemblies and copy them into the same folder as the assembly `.dll` files.

[Advanced code coverage settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_0) are specified in a .runsettings file. This is the configuration file used by unit testing tools.

To exclude:

```
<ModulePaths>
  <Exclude>
   <ModulePath>Fabrikam.Math.UnitTest.dll</ModulePath>
   <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
  </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

As an alternative, you can specify which assemblies should be included. This approach has the drawback that when you add more assemblies to the solution, you have to remember to add them to the list:

```
<ModulePaths>
  <Include>
   <ModulePath>Fabrikam.Math.dll</ModulePath>
   <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
  </Include>
</ModulePaths>
```

If `<Include>` is empty, then code coverage processing includes all assemblies (`.dll` and `.exe` files) that are loaded and for which `.pdb` files can be found, except for items that match a clause in an `<Exclude>` list.
`Include` is processed before `Exclude`.

[More on this here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530(v=vs.120).aspx)

Hope this saves you some time